# Elasticsearch fuzzy matching: How can I get direct hits first?

Tags: elasticsearch, fuzzy-search

I'm using Elasticsearch to search names in a database, and I want it to be fuzzy to allow for minor spelling errors. Based on the advice I've found on the matter, I'm using "match" and "fuzziness" instead of "fuzzy", which definitely seems to be more accurate. This is my query:

```
{ "query": 
    { "match": 
        { "last_name": 
            { "query": "Beach", 
              "type": "phrase",
              "fuzziness": 2
            } 
        }
     }
}
```

However, even though I have numerous results with last_name "Beach" (I know there's at least 100), I also get results with last_name "Beech" and "Berch" in the first 10 hits returned by my query. Can someone help me figure out how to get the exact matches first?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try changing your query to a boolean query with 2 should queries.

The first one being your current query, and then second being a query that only gives exact matches, then give that one a big boost (like 10.0).

That should get your exact matches on top while still listing your partial matches.

Comment: @user3784238 how did you achieve this? one must and one should query? both are with fuzziness or one of them without?

Comment: Can we do the same for suggesters?

Comment: @EricaStockwell-Alpert can you please post the actual ES query using which you fixed this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to edit "Constantijn" answer above to include sample based on his answer, but still not appearing (pending approval). So, I will just put a sample here instead...

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "match": {
            "last_name": {
              "query": "Beach",
              "fuzziness": 2,
              "boost": 1
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "last_name": {
              "query": "Beach",
              "boost": 10
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```